# How to call Laravel Model function with parameter into Vuejs template?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a product table and stock table. In stock table data about product sale and purchase are stored. I need to show the stock of every product base on purchase and sale. So I need to call a model function with product Id in vuejs template to calculate the stock quantity of the product. How to do this, or is there any alternative way? please help me out.

My product controller function is-

```
public function stock() {
    return Product::with(['category', 'stock'])->get();
}
```

My product model function is-

```
public function stock($id){
    $purchase_quantity = Stock::where([['product_id', $id], ['stock_type', 'purchase']])->sum('quantity');
    $sale_quantity = Stock::where([['product_id', $id], ['stock_type', 'sale']])->sum('quantity');
    return $purchase_quantity - $sale_quantity;
}
```

My vuejs template code where in every v-for iteration I want to call the model function-

```
   <tr v-for="product in products.data" :key="product.id">
      <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.category.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.unit }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.stock(product.id) }}</td>
   </tr>
```

Here product.stock(product.id) is not working.
It shows the error-
Too few arguments to function App\Models\Product::stock(), 0 passed

Comment: Remove the `id` parameter from your method definition `stock($id)`, then use `$this->id` instead of `$id` in your method. `['product_id', $id]` => `['product_id', $this->id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `accessor` in this case so

in `Product.php`

```php
protected $appends = ['stocks'];

/**
 * Get the Product's stock
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getStocksAttribute()
{
    $purchase_quantity = Stock::where([['product_id', $this->id], ['stock_type', 'purchase']])->sum('quantity');
    $sale_quantity = Stock::where([['product_id', $this->id], ['stock_type', 'sale']])->sum('quantity');
    return $purchase_quantity - $sale_quantity;
}
```

then in side javascript you can you can get stock in each product row like `product.stocks`

your vuejs code will be like this

```js
<tr v-for="product in products.data" :key="product.id">
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.category.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.unit }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.stocks }}</td>
</tr>
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: I follow your instruction and In controller function I changed Product::with(['category', 'stock'])->get() => Product::with('category')->get(). It's working. Thank you very much.